# Can TP-Link router make phone calls?

Tags: linux, wireless-router, phone

I have a [TP-Link router TL-WR340G](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR340G) (54Mbps Wireless Router) with DSL service provided by a local company which serves it over the landline phone. My landline cord is plugged into an ethernet router which is then plugged into TP-Link wireless router. I can access internet with this wireless router all over my home with all computers.

> Landline Cord [into] Ethernet Router [into] TP-Link Wireless Router
>   [air] Computers

I would add that landline cord is also into a phone device which I use to make calls and that's not cordless.

Now I am accessing internet via WiFi on my laptop and want to ask if is this possible to make landline calls via this same computer I am surfing internet through? What I am asking it to a dial-up via TP-Link router that goes through landline. You see the landline cord is the actual data gateway and is also used to make calls. So it can simultaneously send Data and Voice over the same wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible the way you want.

The landline goes to the ethernet-router. **From that point forward** the signal out of this router carries only internet signal. Even **if** your TP-Link router was analog(phone)/voip-capable it won't have the correct signal if it's not directly connected to the phone-line.

What TP-Link router is this? If it **is** analog(phone)/voip-capable you could plug the phone-line (which is split before your ethernet-router) in the TP-Link and still use your own landline-signal to call other landlines. (You'll need to setup the voip-settings in the TP-Link router)

If it's not analog(phone)/voip-capable the only thing you could do to make calls over the internet from your computer is use a VOIP-service. You will **not** be using your own analog-landline but the internet signal for this. There are a lot of VOIP-providers besides Skype. For example [Voipbuster](http://www.voipbuster.com/peer_to_peer). The mother-company of Voipbuster has many, many, many sub-companies who all have different rates of calling landlines per country.

---

**Edit**: Your TP-Link router is a 54Mbps Wireless Router (TL-WR340G).

I'm sorry to say this router does not have an analog input and/or voice capabilities. The only way you're going to be able to make phone calls directly with your landline is if you buy a VOIP-server solution. If it's just to phone wireless over your landline i would go for a wireless phone. They are much cheaper. (Even those with multiple handsets cost less than a VOIP-server). And even with a VOIP-solution you would have only one line out, so only one call at a time. (These handsets are also less susceptible to interference and easier then some VOIP-app on the PC)

The other option of using VOIP via Skype or Voipbuster still stands and is possible. You can dial out and call other landlines with no problem. Except you won't be using your own active landline but your internet-connection instead.

---

**Edit #2**: Connecting your laptop wireless with your landline can become complicated (especially the setup) if you don't have the necessary expertise.

Buy a Linux-box (which you can place near the landline) and install [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) or [Freeswitch](http://www.freeswitch.org/). Next buy a FXO-card or device which you can connect to the landline. There is some information [here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/VoIP+Gateways). Another one i found is [this one](http://www.x100p.com/products/FXO.php) and should work. `Authentic X100P allows Asterisk to make calls to or receive calls from a traditional analog phone line.` Point is to buy a device which can act as gateway between you analog landline and your VOIP-server (an analog FXO gateway).

And lastly you can use any [VOIP-client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software#Clients) for the laptop to connect to your VOIP-server. There a lots for PCs (like [X-Lite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Lite)) and for my Android phone i used [Sipdroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sipdroid) before i switched to the build in VOIP-client. (When opening your VOIP-box up to the internet it is even possible to use your landline with your cell-phone when not at home:)

Comment: Thanks this makes it clear. I will dig into the router and see if it's analog.

Comment: please see my updated question with router product page

Comment: Added some info to my answer.

Comment: I use Skype Voice as a voip solution. What do you think my options are if I want to connect my phone with my laptop wirelessly?

Comment: Added some more info (Edit #2) to my answer.

Comment: I wish I could upvote the number of times you have made edits. Stay blessed!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use your free landline allowance to make calls from cellphone.
You
Could do this by using your iPhone or android device to remote connect to a pc at home connected to your router (incoming calls)
Then have the modem from the pc lugged into your landline direct.
Use the dialling app on the pc to dial out.
You will suffer some propagation delays.