# Can I use my windows pc to emulate a phone with rj11 cable?

Tags: windows-10, networking

I was wondering if I could plug a RJ11 cable into my pc and then have my pc emulate a phone which I can use to call.

Comment: This is not very likely mostly because smart phones are so prevalent.  https://superuser.com/questions/230693/how-to-make-phone-calls-using-a-pc-modem-headphone-and-no-actual-phone-instrum

Answer (score 1):

This requires an analog modem to be installed. Dont plug the RJ11 into your network jack, as the line is powered and you might end up damaging things.