# Can I make phone calls with the RJ11 port of my (old) laptop motherboard?

Tags: laptop, rj-11

I am using a modern laptop or my iPhone to remote desktop into the old motherboard, connected to the RJ45 Ethernet and the RJ11 phone line.

Can I use the RJ11 to make landline calls?

FWIW, as it’s a salvaged motherboard, I don’t know the make and model. I was able to successfully run Windows 11 21996 on the motherboard. It works flawlessly, except for the fan control circuit.

Comment: Check out [this other thread](https://superuser.com/q/230693/167207). It seems like at one point, software to use a PC like this was quite common. But it all depends on what the onboard modem supports. Not all modems allowed audio to be used like a handset would be used for a PC modem. But you can explore and see what can work!

Comment: "FWIW, as it’s a salvaged motherboard, I don’t know the make and model." So figure out make and model from the BIOS. Figure out if was a software modem (most likely case). "successfully run Windows 11" So is there a modem driver?